# DropDownExtender with CheckBoxList Inside GridViewRow

Tags: asp.net, ajax

The problem I am having is using the DropDownExtender with a checkboxlist in a gridview row the panel displays within the row affecting the row height. Is it possible to get the panel to show ontop of the other rows in the Gridview without affecting the row height?

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="width-25 z-index-neg1" HeaderStyle-CssClass="nowrap width-25" HeaderText="<div class='padding-top-sm border-left-white border-bottom-orange height-16'><span class='margin-left-2'>Reaction</span></div>">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Panel ID="pnlReactions" runat="server" CssClass="PnlDesign display-none">
                                        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkListReactions" runat="server" Width="170px" CssClass="z-index-800 chkListReactions"></asp:CheckBoxList>
                                    </asp:Panel>
                                     <asp:Label ID="lblReactions" runat="server" CssClass="txtbox border-all" Height="16px" Width="195px" onclick="popupReactions(this, '1');"></asp:Label>
                                    <cc1:DropDownExtender
                                        ID="deReactions"
                                        runat="server"
                                        TargetControlID="lblReactions"
                                        DropDownControlID="pnlReactons">
                                    </cc1:DropDownExtender>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Thanks

Comment: Got it was position:absolute

Answer (score 0):

Think about using the css class "overflow:visible" on the `<td>` elements.